# How to know the real address(which NIC) is connected in a gRPC function handler on SERVER side?

Tags: grpc, grpc-c++

When I implement an `::grpc::Service`, I should implement the virtual funtions.

If I bind all address ("0.0.0.0:50051") by calling `AddListeningPort`, how can I get the real server ip of each gRPC call? Or how can I know which network card was connected of each gRPC call? Is there any clue in `ServerContext`?

Thanks.

```cpp
grpc::Status DetectServicerImpl::Query(grpc::ServerContext* context, const Empty* request,
                                       QueryResult* query_result) {
  exporter->QueryResult(query_result);
  return grpc::Status::OK;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it in server interceptor like this in Java:

```java
public class CustomServerInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
        SocketAddress socketAddress = call.getAttributes()
                                          .get(Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR);
        // ...
    }
}
```

And the `TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR` value is `remote-addr`